# How to manage navigation links in multi-language website?

Tags: joomla-3.x, navigation

I have some trouble to understand how the navigation links between different language versions work in Joomla! 3.6 So I just got a website to manage - http://www.pontech.co.uk/en/

When you choose the BG version of the website in the up right corner it sends you to a http://www.pontech.bg/bg/ version of the website and RO version to a Romanian version.

Where can I manage this functionality? I want to change where it links the users.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the languages' URL code (en, bg, ro).

Then you need to go:
**Extensions -> Languages -> Content Languages**

Select/Click the language you want to edit and then change the field called: **URL Language Code**.

ATTENTION: Changing the URL language code, will make all your old links to result to 404 errors.

So, if you change the **ro** to **romania**, then the previous url: `example.com/ro/page` will be accessible only at `example.com/romania/page` and the old url will be a 404.

As a further note - if you want your default/main language to be displayed without a language url code (e.g. let's say english is your default lang and you want your english pages have no `/en` in their URLs, then you need to edit this on the **System - Language Filter plugin**.

Go to **Extensions->Plugins**, do a search filter "Lang" - you will find 2 plugins. Select/Edit the Language Filter plugin, and set the field **Remove URL Language Code** to Enabled (YES).

This setting will remove the language URL code and redirect all the pages of your default language.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to change the language and reload the same page and not redirect to the home page you have to associate that menu item with the appropriate one of every other language.

> Edit your menu item -> Associations Tab

Also do the same with your articles.